# Color doesn't show when running python script in cmd / batch file

Tags: python, cmd, prettytable

I'm trying to print a table with colored text using prettytable. When I run it [in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPZ93.png) it works.

However if I then try to run it [with Windows cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzx27.png) no colors are shown

relevant Python Code:

```
...
#Colours
green = '\033[92m'
yellow = '\033[93m'
red = '\033[91m'
reset = '\033[0m'
...
t = PrettyTable(['Datum', 'Anzahl', ...])
t.add_row([line[0], green+str(line[1])+reset, ...])
print(t)
```

Answer (score -2):

windows cmd is not that much modified and does not provide that number of functions that VS code gives you. Colour is one of the most highlighting feature of VS CODE.